# RoR security with POST method: where - how occurs the validation - howto optimize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, security, post

In some forums I made the experience that newbies are sometimes getting not very helpful answers (to describe my former experiences nicely) when asking questions about things that are obvious to more experienced users.
So please excuse as I fear this is one of those questions - nevertheless I want to understand it and hope someone can explain the following to me in simple words?

**How does RoR behave from a security perspective - when POST is used?

In specific:**

**1.** Where does validation occur in the belows example
**1.1** ServerSide?
**1.2** ClientSide?
**1.3** Both?
**1.3.1** If both, the remaining points should be sorted...(right?)

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

**2**. If validation occurs only on the server site:
**2.1** Couldn´t that lead to a situation where someone uses a script to "overload" the server with such invalid requests and keeping my server busy so it wont respond to other requests?
**2.2** Even there would be (an additional) clientSide validation performed (or implemented if that isn't handled) could bypassing the ClientSide validation by entering the URL POST STRIG directly flood my server with useless requests (Traffic, RAM,...)?
**3.** In case the validation occurs only on the client side:
**3.1** Could an attacker bypass that by triggering the (guessed) POST String from the browser directly and insert something to my DB that I dont want to see there?
**3.2** How would I mitigate that?

I am not sure if I explain my thoughts well enough as I am no programmer nor a hacker, but as I work related with a lot business logic and processes this question about how POST really behaves and how RoR handles it keeps my brain busy.

Your time for crafting a short answer in simple words is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation in the above case would happen on the server side.

2.1 As for invalid requests, if someone is trying to abuse your system by flooding it with invalid requests ( it may be form POSTs or otherwise ) which might lead to a Denial of service (DoS) you should consider using tools like fail2ban, there are many tools to help you handle abusive clients so may just want to google and figure out what works best in your setup.

2.2 Ideally you should have some client side validation, its leads to much better user experience and using tools and services to handle DoS or DDoS should take care of abusive clients

3.1 Always have server side validations and DB level constraints. Your data integrity is paramount, so ideally it should be perfect condition irrespective of what client or framework you use.

3.2 Server side validations and DB constraints to maintain data integrity.

These are good questions and worrying about security is good.

For DoS or DDoS attacks you can't do much in your code, although these problems have been solved before so you should get a lot of information on them, just by googling them.

For stuff that you should be careful in your code, Read:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Also, this http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-security-tutorial-and-rails-security-guide/

Comment: excellent answer, thank you! Are you aware (no worries, I might find it in the docs somewhere I assume) how heroku would handle abusive behavior from (i.e. POST methods by form or likewise)? Also: I couldn´t find any fail2ban gem that would at least allow me connecting to the logs and include in my backend / map with related useraccounts to see if any useraccounts are compromised / targeted / misued / locked-out. I assumed anybody must have done that before...?

Comment: I don't have anything in production on Heroku, so I am not sure. If you are using Heroku and can't figure it out, you can talk to their support and find out what should be done. Most infrastructure providers have some of sort of recommendations for handling DoS and DDoS attacks, some already have services in place to handle them ( its possible Heroku already does )